# How can I make a hidden button menu appear/disappear with a scrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want to have `Buttons` hidden above my normal content in the `ScrollView`, which will appear when I swipe down. Currently, I have these `Buttons` in a `StackView` inside the `ScrollView`. I want the view to snap between two positions where the `Buttons` are not visible and where they are, but also, I may need to scroll if the actual content is larger than the screen.

I've tried `contentOffset`. This works at first, but then if it is scrolled and the content is smaller than the screen, it will always show the `Buttons`.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Image for clarification:

[image]

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: So far I just have this in the storyboard, no real code to get the snapping effect I want.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you describe. But as my imagination what you need is set contentInset for scrollview with negative Top value, like this:
`UIScrollview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`

Comment: This is a good start, but it won't give me the sort of snapping effect that I want. What clarification do you need? I'd be happy to clarify

Comment: I'm not sure about snapping effect. Is it like bouncing back when you scroll view down and release finger ?

Comment: And which action you need to hide and show these button ?  If you scroll down, these button show up, then release the finger, these button hide, how can user tap them.